# Best way of bundling required assembly with VSTO?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, vsto, add-in

I have a C# Word VSTO Add-in project, 'A', that I'm developing in MSVC2010. It references an external assembly, 'B.dll', built separately (in C++/CLR, for what its worth).

Now, everything compiles fine, but when the 'A' is loaded in Word (i.e. hitting F5), I get tan exception "Could not load file or assembly 'B.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found."

I'm guessing that in loading the add-in 'A.dll', Word couldn't find 'B.dll' on which it is dependent. I checked and the two are in the same directory (B's 'Copy Local' is set to true in A's references list).

What's the cleanest, simplest and/or easiest way of resolving this?

Comment: all the tags you used are important but I think the most important is `C#` therefore I added it to your question. I had to delete one of tag, unfortunately :( hope you agree with my choice.

Comment: Does B.dll have any missing dependencies?

Comment: I don't think so. Is there a definitive way of checking?